# Installed plugins disappear after reinstalling 2.14

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, osx

[image]I am using Kyng Chaos package QGIS 2.14 on Mac OS 10.11.6, and uninstalled/reinstalled the software recently and each time I re-open a project I lose all my user-specified preferences that I initiated the last time it was open.

My installed plugins need to be re-checked for them appear in the drop-down bars, and the text size/font/zoom ratio changes etc.. Any suggestions for where I should set up a preferences cache? Or where I can look to access my old settings?

Comment: I changed the file path in settings>options to the project_templates folder in .qgis2. it worked briefly, but then it reset, adding another '//' to the filepath.

Comment: need to know how to stop qgis from replacing the file path highlighted in image with the following: users/'username'/.qgis2//project_templates